# Firebase authWithOAuthRedirect fails to handle bad credentials error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've accidentally used wrong Facebook App Secret in Dashboard. Because of that I got into endless loop of authentication because `onAuth` callback was always invoked with `null`. Only after I switched to `authWithOAuthPopup`, the callback with error got invoked and I was able to find out about the error.

There was this request
`https://auth.firebase.com/v2/scent/auth/session?&requestId=3zu08w12z46cj6wjno91acp1ylhr17yuzqfn&requestKey=OUYJb0pS4qpbuajatNjTymiG9tzqrpli&v=js-2.3.2&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true`

And the response
`{"error":{"code":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS","message":"Invalid authentication credentials provided."}}`

Then I tried Google with bad secret and issue is pretty much the same. Even the error message. I guess some sort of standard.

Twitter is somewhat better, because error is shown directly in the window `{"error":{"code":"ROUTE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Route not found."}}`. Not ideal, but at least developer knows there is something wrong instead of having endless loop.

I did not tried GitHub, because I am not going to be use that anyway.

Comment: I have the same issue